# How to make an image return to a certain point?

Tags: ios, uiimage

I have an image which moves along the screen and when it gets to the end it should move back to where it started. Its coordinates for where is starts are 0,0 so i thought i should just do this

```
     if (image < -5){

     image.center = CGPointMake(0,0);
}
```

The only problem is when it gets to the end of the screen it jumps up and continues the cycle.
How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say 'it jumps up', do you mean it moves a bit further up the screen?

I guess what's going on is originally you are setting its `origin` to `(0, 0)`, but with the code you posted you are setting its `centre` to `(0, 0)`; these are two different things.

Try this instead:

```
if (image < -5){
     image.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.frame.size.width, image.frame.size.height);
}
```